# PySpark select top N from multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Pyspark dataframe

```
Tick | Long Position  | Short Position
ADM  | $25.5          | $12.2
INT  | $300           | $120
CITI | $-12           | $9.1
```

I need to select top 3 from both "Long Position" and "Short Position". From the data above what I want will be something like below. How to do it?

```
Tick | Position | PnL
INT  | Long     | $300
INT  | Short    | $120
ADM  | Long     | $25.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial idea, would be to union the two columns and create one dataframe which is in the structure of your output and then take the top 3. I just tried this in Scala, it should work also with pyspark.

```
val y = someDF.select("Tick", "Long").withColumn("type", lit("Long")).withColumnRenamed("Long", "PnL")
val z = someDF.select("Tick", "Short").withColumn("type", lit("Short")).withColumnRenamed("Short", "PnL")

println(y.union(z).sort(desc("PnL")).take(3))
```

Because you are doing everything with spark API, I think it should give you good performance as well. Let me know how it goes!